# Jquery map json arrays with $.map

Tags: jquery

I am having confusion on how to do it with $.map function instead of regular `$.each`.
I have json data like this.

```
var arr = {
 "x1" :[11,22,33],
 "y1":[44,55,66],
 "y2":[77,88,99]
};
```

And result should be 
array = [[x1,y1,y2], ...]

`var result = [[11,44,77],[22,55,88],[33,66,99]];`

And I want function to be dynamic , it should not depend on arr.x1 etc .For example If i give it array like

```
var arr2 = {
 "aaa" :[11,22,33],
 "sss":[44,55,66],
 "dd":[77,88,99],
 "dddd":[77,88,99],
};
```

It should add up all array like above dynamically as it have now 4 sub arrays so result should be three sub-arrays of four elements each.
I should be able to do it with `$.each` etc but purpose is to learn $.map.

**UPDATE:**
My guess is pure $.map solution will be something like 
nested maps:

```
_elements = $.map(_elements, function(e) {
    return [$.map(e,function(v) {
        return v;
    })];
});
```

Comment: Your `arr` array isn't actually an array; it's an object. As such, the order of your result can't be guaranteed.

Comment: You say `arr2` should produce 4 sub-arrays. Don't you mean it should produce three sub-arrays of four elements each?

Comment: @Blazemonger, You are right.three sub-arrays of four elements each

Comment: Then you're not trying to map the object to an array; you're trying to [transpose a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). `$.map` is a one-to-one transformation engine.

Comment: Agree with @Blazemonger - in fact you should definitely not use variable names like `arr` and `arr2`, because these names will confuse you into thinking the objects are arrays when they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your array like this :

```
var arr = {
 "x1" :[11,22,33],
 "y1":[44,55,66],
 "y2":[77,88,99]
};
var keys = Object.keys(arr), result = [], l=arr[keys[0]].length;
for(var i=0; i<l; i++) result.push($.map(keys, function(k){ return arr[k][i] }));
```

This builds exactly the array you're asking for.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/EkUxIY/1/)

Comment: Yes it does work. But is it doable purely in $.map ? by using nestes $.map ?

Comment: @django I don't see how. `$.map` uses an implicit loop through each property of the object, each of which is unconnected to the other properties. A map is a one-to-one transformation. You seem to want a [transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: And we are politely informing you that your guess is wrong. :-)

Comment: If you want to use `$.map` a little more, you can build the `keys` array like this : `var keys = $.map(arr, function(_,k){ return k})`. But, just like @Blazemonger, I fail to see how nested `$.map` could be used here (and more importantly why complicate the code just to nest `$.map`).